# Get Azure AD Graph Token if already Authenticated

Tags: azure, authentication, authorization, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm pretty new to Azure AD Graph and the authentication process. I was able to incorporate a single-sign on using the Azure AD Graph client as found in this example using a .NET MVC application: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web

My dilemma is that even though I've authenticated my session, it's still requesting that I login again to perform the actions found in the controller below:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    if (Request.QueryString["reauth"] == "True")
    {

        //Send an OpenID Connect sign -in request to get a new set of tokens.
        // If the user still has a valid session with Azure AD, they will not be prompted for their credentials.
        // The OpenID Connect middleware will return to this controller after the sign-in response has been handled.


        HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
            .Authentication.Challenge(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
}

// Access the Azure Active Directory Graph Client
ActiveDirectoryClient client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();

    // Obtain the current user's AD objectId
    string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

    // Query and obtain the current user object from the Azure AD Graph Client
    User user = (User)client.Users.
        Where(u => u.ObjectId
        .Equals(userObjectID, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).
        ExecuteSingleAsync().
        Result;

    // Get the employee Id from Azure AD (via a directory extension)
    IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> extendedProperty = user.GetExtendedProperties();
    object extendedProp = extendedProperty["extension_ExtensionId_employeeID"];


    // Hash the employee Id
    var empId = PasswordHash.ArgonHashString(extendedProp.ToString(), PasswordHash.StrengthArgon.Moderate);
    // Send to the view for testing only
    ViewBag.EmployeeName = user.DisplayName;
    ViewBag.EmployeeEmail = user.Mail;
    ViewBag.EmployeeId = empId;

    return View();
}
```

The error I get is a:

Server Error in '/' Application
Authorization Required

With the following lines of code in the yellow box:

```
Line 22:             if (token == null || token.IsEmpty())
Line 23:             {
Line 24:                 throw new Exception("Authorization Required.");
Line 25:             }
Line 26:             return token;
```

Since I'm fairly new to the authentication piece, I need a little guidance on how-to obtain the current session token so I don't get this error.

I'm using the Azure AD Graph because I'm obtaining a specific directory extension in Azure that I wasn't able to obtain through Microsoft Graph (for right now and based on my current deadline).

Any advice will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the token is null , user needs to re-authorize . As shown in [code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web/blob/master/WebAppGraphAPI/Controllers/UsersController.cs#L49) , you could use try catch statement to handle the exception :

```
            try
            {

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {                        
                //
                // The user needs to re-authorize.  Show them a message to that effect.
                //
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "AuthorizationRequired";
                return View(userList);
            }
```

Show message to user(for example , [Index.cshtml](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web/blob/master/WebAppGraphAPI/Views/Users/Index.cshtml#L51) in Users view folder) :

```
@if (ViewBag.ErrorMessage == "AuthorizationRequired")
{
    <p>You have to sign-in to see Users. Click @Html.ActionLink("here", "Index", "Users", new { reauth = true }, null) to sign-in.</p>
}
```

If you want to directly send an OpenID Connect sign-in request to get a new set of tokens instead show error message to user , you can use :

```
           catch (Exception e)
            {
              ....

             HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
                .Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties {RedirectUri = "/"},
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
               .....
            }
```

If the user still has a valid session with Azure AD, they will not be prompted for their credentials.The OpenID Connect middleware will return to current controller after the sign-in response has been handled.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I ended up doing that at the end of the work day and had users redirect to reauthorize the application again. I realized that there are two things going on - the single-sign on is authenticating the user while the LINQ query is requesting specific authorization to the Azure AD graph API. I've interpreted it in a way that the authentication is providing access to the application, but the authorization piece is giving specific delegated permissions to a specific resource.